# If a category admits binary products and pullbacks, is it true that the product functor $Z \times -$ preserves pullbacks, for every object $Z$?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, pullback

$\require{AMScd}$
I have provided a proof of this fact by myself. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with binary products (denoted by $\times$) and pullbacks. Let $Z$ be any object. If I consider a pullback square
$$\begin{CD} P @>h>> A \\ @VkVV @VVfV \\ B @>>g> C \end{CD}$$ 
then I can perform
$$\begin{CD} Z\times P @>Z\times h>> Z\times A \\ @VZ\times kVV @VVZ\times fV \\ Z\times B @>>Z\times g> Z\times C \end{CD}$$ 
Denote by $(Q,p,q)$ the pullback of $(Z \times f, Z\times g)$. By the universal property of the pullback there exists a unique $\alpha : Z \times P \to Q$. The other way around, I can consider
$$Q \xrightarrow{p} Z \times A \xrightarrow{\pi_A} A$$
and
$$Q \xrightarrow{q} Z \times B \xrightarrow{\pi_B} B$$
and these satisfy
$$f\circ\pi_A \circ p = g \circ \pi_B \circ q,$$
so that there exists a unique $\sigma:Q \to P$. In addition, we have $\tau:Q\to Z$ given by
$$\pi_Z \circ (Z \times g) \circ q = \tau = \pi_Z \circ (Z \times f)\circ p$$
and hence there exists a unique $\beta: Q\to Z \times P$. A direct check then shows that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are each other inverses. However, I am surprised I didn't find any reference concerning this so either I made a silly mistake or there exists a more general result of which this is just a particular instance.

**Question:** Is anybody aware of a reference where I may find stated/proved this property?

Comment: This is just a special case of the more general property of limits to commute with each other, perhaps that is why you had a hard time finding a reference for this.

Comment: @asdq I see: product of pullbacks is pullback of products, up to iso. If one pullback is the trivial pullback of (Z = Z = Z) then I find what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @asdq If you don't mind to convert your comment into an answer, I will accept it so we remove this thread from the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a special case of the more general property of limits to commute with each other, perhaps that is why you had a hard time finding a reference for this.